# How do I retrieve custom properties of a custom open graph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I defined a custom Open Graph action (e.g. "drive") and a custom object ("car") with custom properties ("color", "make"), then added the meta tags to the object page and verified with the Object debugger. I also published few actions in my timeline. 
When I use the action API to view the "drive" actions ("/me/[name_space]:drive") I see all the actions and the Objects with their default properties (ids, titles..) but no custom properties. 
How can I retrieve the Objects with all their custom properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably too late, but I encountered with the same problem today.

It seems that the custom action `/me/[name_space]:drive` only provides the standard properties, but I found that if you also include the object type you can retrieve it with the custom ones:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook/recipes
```

or in your example:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/[name_space]:drive/car
```